# Identifying block variation in PHP render_callback function

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am wondering if it is possible to identify which **block variation** is used within the `render_callback` function.

Currently I am registering a **variation** with Javascript, because I found no PHP function doing this:

Javascript:

```
registerBlockVariation('my/solaredge', {
    name: 'CO2',
    title: 'SolarEdge CO2',
});
```

I was in the hopes, that PHP somehow may know what variation it is being rendered.
The closest thing I was able to find was `register_block_style()`, this one I can identify since `get_block_wrapper_attributes()` returns the classes string with the style class.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/404141/block-variations-registration-in-php Does the  answer given for that question help?

Comment: @S.Walsh nope, i am not looking to register anything. I want to figure out what block variation is in use.